# AS3 string to class

Tags: actionscript-3, class

How can I convert a string to a class without getDefinitionByName because that class is not linked to a library item and getDefinitionByName only works with classes that are linked to library or allready initialized! Is there a way? Or I have to initialize every class I want to use?! That would be soooo stupid of Adobe!

Comment: +1,that's interesting, I dont know about another name too!

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean with classes that are "already initialized" and not wanting to initialize every class you want to use. how would you use them if not by initializing them?

Answer (score 3):

`getDefinitionByName()` will work with any class name, linked to library or not. Your problem is likely that since you're not mentioning the class name in the code, it's not in your swf at all. You will have to make sure the class is used at atleast one place in your code, if not it will not be compiled in.

This can be as simple as just putting them on a line in your Main-class:

```
public class Main {

    public function Main(){
        ClassYouWant;
        AnotherClass;

        codeThatDoesStuff();
    }

}
```

Comment: Nevermind, what I want cannot be done! In any language except does who have eval. The idea was that I would create numerous classes and not have to initiate them anywhere!

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking when you say "not have to initiate them anywhere". Can you provide some kind of example?

Comment: I have a game. I want every level to be a class that extends LevelTpl class like "class Level1 extends LevelTpl". Then I want to call any level like "Level"+curLevel. The problem is there is no eval in AS3, so I would have to use getDefinitionByName, but getDefinitionByName only works with allready initialized classes! So if I make 100 Levels => 100 classes, I must initiate them all before using them! I was hoping I don't have to do that!

Comment: It will take you approx two minutes to write a short little loop that traces out your level names if you name them like that. Copy the trace output into a class that is used in your game and you're done.

Eval wouldn't help you here, since the problem is not that i doesn't find the class, it's that they're not referred to and thus not included at all.

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:**

If you want to avoid including class references (as suggested by @grapefrukt) you'll have to compile those classes in a library and reference that from your main application as an RSL (Runtime Shared Library)

**The long answer:**

There is no other way to create a Class by its name than to use getDefinitionByName().

However there are several ways to compile your code. By default, if you have a single application that doesn't include libraries, it will not compile classes that are not referenced in your code. You call this stupid, but there's a pretty good reason for that: it reduces the size of your swf and so the download time of your application.

If you use libraries there are three ways they can be referenced from your main application:

- merged into code
- runtime shared library (RSL)
- external

The first option will take all (and only) the classes from the library that were referenced in the main application. This results in a smaller swf size.

The second option will compile the entire library into a separate swf, which is loaded by the main application. This results in a bigger file size, but the same swf can be used by several applications. And what's most important to you: all classes are in that swf, so they can be referenced by getDefinitionByName() without having to include the class in your main app.

[image]

Comment: @Alex You can link to RSL's in flash CS5 too (through 'advanced ActionScript properties'), but I suppose that to compile your library you'll need FlashBuilder or do it at the commandline with the mxmlc compiler. mxmlc can compile ActionScript-only libraries too; it's not limited to Flex. So, what you want to do can be done, but it may not be easy to you.

Comment: @Alex Look what I just found: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/how-to-use-an-external-library-in-your-flash-projects/